# Match every item in between two words in a comma separated list

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a comma separated numbers, I want to match every item after `START` or before `END` if any of the keyword exists.

I got most of the test cases correctly using

```
(?:.*?START|END.*)(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+
```

except those that `START` appears after `END` or multiple instances of `START` and `END` exist.

| input | matches |
| --- | --- |
| `123,45678,789,777,888,1234` | `123`,`45678`,`789`,`777`,`888`,`1234` |
| `123,START,789,777,888,1234` | `789`,`777`,`888`,`1234` |
| `123,45678,789,777,END,1234` | `123`,`45678`,`789`,`777` |
| `123,START,789,777,END,1234` | `789`,`777` |
| `123,END,789,777,START,1234` | `123` |
| `123,START,789,START,777,END,1234` | `789`,`777` |
| `123,START,789,END,777,END,1234` | `789` |
| `123,END,789,START,777,END,1234` | `123` |

Here's the [regex101 project](https://regex101.com/r/v3vf4E/1/) I was trying, I'm using PCRE2(PHP7.3).

Comment: Can you clarify `123,START,789,START,777,END,1234` requirement?

Comment: What is unclear? `789` and `777` are expected since they appear after the first occurrence of `START` and before the first occurrence of `END`.

Comment: @anubhava While multiple `START` or `END` exists. Always use the first one and ignore further instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might fix your pattern by adding a restriction to find `START` that has no `END` before it:

```php
(?:^(?:(?!END).)*?START|END.*)(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJg6T2/2).

Here, `^(?:(?!END).)*?START` (instead of `.*?START`) matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?!END).)*?` - any char, other than line break chars, as few as possible, that does not start an `END` char sequence
- `START` - a `START` char sequence.

You can also use

```php
(?:\G(?!\A)|^(?:(?:(?!END).)*?START)?)(?:(?!END).)*?\K\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJg6T2/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|^(?:(?:(?!END).)*?START)?)` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or (`|`) start of a string (`^`) and then an optional occurrence of any text up to the first occurrence of `START` that is not preceded with `END` (`(?:(?:(?!END).)*?START)?`)
- `(?:(?!END).)*?` - any char, other than line break chars, zero or more times but as few as possible, that does not start an `END` char sequence
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `\d+` - one or more digits.